# Nativescript Angular CLI generate output path

Tags: angular-cli, nativescript

I'm just starting with nativescript angular CLI. When I do something like "tns g c mycomponent" .. it generates it in the root folder, so into /app/mycomponent

But how can I change it so that it generates it in /src/app/mycomponent .. or just /src/app/ as default root to generate .. just like a normal ng g c component would do.

I have installed nativescript-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript doesn't use the same structure as Angular, and that is unfortunately not something you can change.

The [official documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/getting-started/project-structure) shows the default structures.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics#generating-components-modules-directives-etc), you will have to mention the full path to create component inside specific module / folder.